# Does みな have an origin, or at least one that can be theorized about?

Tags: etymology

I personally think this question is self explanatory, so I'm going to add context. I searched up the etymology for 皆, not the kanji but its reading, and didn't find anything for it. It may be み with a suffix that's called な or み as a suffix with な. It originally meant 全部, or 総て, adverbially too, then changed to mean everyone. Why?

Comment: Also, I recently learned ghost kanji are different from kanji without readings/meanings, I forgot the post that talks about it and I don't want to make a duplicate question. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ancestor of [みな](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AA) in Old Japanese was *mi<sub>2</sub>na*. (It is certainly unrelated to honorific prefix [[御]{み}](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BE%A1#Japanese), which was *mi<sub>1</sub>* in Old Japanese.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese#Vowels has summary of reconstructions of *i<sub>1</sub>*, *i<sub>2</sub>* etc.

According to Bjarke Frellesvig (2010)'s reconstruction, *mi<sub>2</sub>na* would be /mwina/.

According to Alexander Vovin (2020)'s reconstruction, *mi<sub>2</sub>na* would be /mɨna/. (He usually uses symbol *ï*, but both *ɨ* and *ï* refer to the same vowel, [high central unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_central_unrounded_vowel); double dot over symbol of vowel indicates central vowel.)

Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", pages 319-321):

> 2.6 Collective Pronouns
>
> There are two collective pronouns in Western Old Japanese: *mïna* and *morǝ*
> ‘all.’
>
> 2.6.1 *Collective Pronoun* mïna
>
> The collective pronoun *mïna* ‘all’ is attested in phonographic spelling in Western Old Japanese four times. It may refer to both animate and inanimate nouns. When modifying a noun, *mïna* ‘all’ is always found in postposition. It is interesting to note that the case marker may be found both after the modified noun and after the modifying *mïna* with no apparent change in meaning as in *pitǝ-nǝ mïna* and *pitǝ mïna-nǝ* ‘all people’ found in the examples below.
>
> ...
>
> Cognates of the Old Japanese collective pronoun *mïna* ‘all’ are attested in several modern Ryukyuan dialects: Uezu, Maejima *nna*; Kowan *n:na*; Agarinakasone *ṃ:na* (Uchima and Arakaki 2000: 410), Shuri *’Nna* (RKJ 1983: 436). There is also the Oku form *minna*, but it looks like a loanword from modern Standard Japanese *minna* ‘all,’ especially since there is another collective pronoun *muttuu* in Oku. *Muttuu* is apparently related to another Old Japanese collective pronoun *morǝ* ‘all,’ which will be discussed in the section 2.6.2. In Old Ryukyuan the collective pronoun in question is attested only in the *Haytong ceykwukki* and the *Ryūka*. It probably was pronounced as *mina* in the late fifteenth–early sixteenth century according to the Korean transcription *mina* (미나) in the *Haytong ceykwukki* (1501 CE), becoming later *’Nna* or *’Nnya*, as different existing spellings in the *Ryūka* indicate: *mina* (みな), *nna* (んな), *nnya* (んにや) (Hokama 1995: 639).
>
> ...
>
> The reconstruction of the proto-Japonic archetype should be *mǝyna or *muyna. It is possible to speculate that *-na represents a plural marker *-na*, as was discussed in section 1.2.1.4, while the remainder *mǝy-/*muy- is the root of the collective pronoun. If this is true, and if the original vowel was *ǝ and not *u, it is quite possible that *mǝy can be derived from *mǝrǝy according to Whitman‘s law, and is therefore a variant of the another Old Japanese collective pronoun *morǝ* ‘all’ < *mǝrǝ, which will be discussed in the next section 2.6.2.

(Old Japanese *i<sub>2</sub>*, besides *əi and *ui, can also come from *oi. See [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:About_Proto-Japonic#Vowel_correspondences).)

Comment: Curious if there's anything more about the purported plural marker _*-na_?  I'm familiar with _-ra_, but no such _-na_.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi A lot; see Vovin, p. 119ff. and, Frellesvig p. 131 for the theory that it is an archaic genitive instead; also Ratte p. 67ff. for Unger's position that it is merely an allophonic form of usual nö.

Comment: @AlexanderZ. - I'm familiar with this as a genitive. Does Vovin explain better his views on this as a plural marker? And what is the title of the relevant work?  "Vovin (2020)" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Those books are: Bjarke Frellesvig (2010) "A History of the Japanese Language"; Alexander Vovin (2020) "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese". It seems that Vovin considered *mina* (preserved in modern 源{みなもと} and 港{みなと}) to be "HON-water" (御(*mi*) + *na*).

Comment: @Arfrever, ah, ya, from his idea that _namida_ must be cognate with a Thai term, as mentioned at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B6%99#Japanese. Frankly, I find that a bit of a stretch -- even if _namida_ were a borrowing from proto-Thai, there's enough evidence of Japonic _mi_ meaning "water" to obviate any need to postulate "honorable water" as a gloss for the always-compounding element _mina-_ in these various water-related terms. — Separately, is there anything at all about _na_ as a plural marker, as in the last quoted paragraph of your answer post above?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Vovin's evidence seems to be more for this *na* not being case particle, than having plural marker function.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi (I can later ask my own question and answer it myself by copying few pages from book, if this is good idea...)